# php header multiple site header response 200 in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Basically i want to input multiple site url in textarea and check header response of these input. my code  mention below:

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Goutte\Client;
    //use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
    
    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    
    
        public function Datanewsub(Request $request){
    
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $url= $request->input('url');
            $arr = explode("\n", $url);
            foreach($arr as $x => $val){
                echo $val.'<br>';
                $res = $client->request('GET', $val);
                echo $res->getStatusCode().'<br>';
            }
    
            return view('scraper');
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to show multiple urls in your `<textarea>`?

Comment: user put multi url in text area and  i  want to check header response of each url weather its 200 or 404 etc

Comment: Then why echo it if you just want to check if the status code is 200 or 404

Comment: simply create an array and use if condition with `if($res->getStatusCode() == 200 || $res->getStatusCode()  == 404) ` then save the values in the associative array.

Comment: because its our requirement to print status of each url

Comment: I fount this-> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `GET https://vegibit.com/how-to-set-up-form-submission-in-laravel/%0D` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: <!doctype html> <html lang="en-US"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, i (truncated...)

Comment: %0D is a carriage return. Try trimming the URLs before making the request. `$res = $client->request('GET', trim($val));`

Answer (score 2):

You could handle it like following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller extends BaseController
{

    public function yourAction(Request $request){

        $client = new Client();
        $urls = explode("\n", $request->input('url'));

        $responses = [];
        foreach($urls as $key => $url){
            $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
            $responses[$url] = $response->getStatusCode();
        }

        return view('scraper', compact('responses'));
    }

}
```

And in your scraper.blade.php view file:

```php
@foreach($responses as $key => $response)

    {{$key}} => {{$response}}

@endforeach
```

And you should definitely also add some exception handling within your foreach in the controller action - if there is invalid input for example you will probably get an exception from the guzzle http client.

Comment: GuzzleHttp response 404 with all url except last one 200

Comment: How does your input exactly look like?

Comment: i input multi url in textarea and pass these url to foreach loop foreach($urls as $key => $url){
            $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
            $responses[$url] = $response->getStatusCode();
        }

Comment: Did you try to debug - it could be possible that you have a \r in all your URLS except the last one.